# Sorting embedded document in Symfony2 with Doctrine ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm unable to sort the embedded document. Here is my code.

Children.php

```
namespace Acme\CCBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Children {
/..
    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Vaccine")
     */
    protected $vaccine = array();
}
```

Vaccine.php

```
namespace Acme\CCBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Vaccine
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Date
     */
    protected $recordDate;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $vaccineName;
}
```

In my controller: RecordController.php

```
public function showVaccineAction($id) {
        $child = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                ->getRepository('AcmeCCBundle:Children')
                ->find($id);

        $vac = $child->getVaccine();

        return $this->render(
                        'AcmeCCBundle:Record:show_vaccine.html.twig', array('vac' => $vac)
        );
    }
```

I just be able query all the vaccine of a child, and it's not ordered. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can't sort embedded document in mongodb (respectively in doctrine odm).

you can use two option:

1. update embedded document with sorting - you'll recreate documents, so no need to sorting(by default mongodb return documents sorted by created order).
   use this case if documents is not many and/or storing sorted result permanently
2. use aggregation in mongodb -you'll denormalize by embedded document and sort by any way.
   big minus - the result may be difference from original document and can't hydrate to ODM class(problem with mapping to document).
   use this case if documents is too many and/or result stored temporary (e.g. only showing in template)

PS. no sorting command in your code ;)